# Drop dataframe rows that meet two specific criteria (values) using Python

Tags: python, sorting, filter

I would like to be able to keep information that is about players that are <=25 years of age and <=200 lbs.

Here is what I have done:

Code 1:

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
   
data = {'Nage':['John Doe', 'Billy Bob', 'Franky Bill'],
        'Age':['27','25','27'],
        'Weight':['210','185','220']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Age']=df['Age'].astype(str).astype(float)
df['Weight']=df['Weight'].astype(str).astype(float)    
    
# Visualize the dataframe 
print(df.head()) 
  
# Print the shape of the dataframe 
print(df.shape)
```

Expected output1:

```
          Nage   Age  Weight
0     John Doe  27.0   210.0
1    Billy Bob  25.0   185.0
2  Franky Bill  27.0   220.0
(3, 3)
```

Code2:

```
# Filter all rows for which the player's 
# age is less than or equal to 25 and weight less than or equal to 200 lbs
df_filtered = df[df['Age'] <= 25] 

df_filtered2 = df_filtered[df_filtered['Weight'] <= 200]

# Print the new dataframe 
print(df_filtered.head()) 
  
# Print the shape of the dataframe 
print(df_filtered.shape)
```

Expected output2:

```
        Nage   Age  Weight
1  Billy Bob  25.0   185.0
(1, 3)
```

Can anyone think of a simpler way of doing this? Possibly with "and" or "|"

I have tried

```
df.drop((df[df['Age'] >= 25.0 | df['Weight'] >= 200.0]).index, inplace=True)
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

If I replace `|` with `or`, I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution: You simply need parentheses around the two sub-conditions:

```
df.drop((df[(df['Age'] >= 25.0) | (df['Weight'] >= 200.0)]).index, inplace=True)
```

Alternatively depending upon user application they could use "&" or "|". I found that the "&" operator works best in my case so that it specifies both criteria must be met in order to drop a row.